# Byte[] and java.lang.OutOfMemoryError reading file by bits

Tags: java, file, memory, file-io

I am trying to write a reader which reads files by bits but I have a problem with large files. I tried to read file with 100 mb and it took over 3 minutes but it worked.

However, then I tried file with 500 mb but it didn't even started. Because of this line:

```
byte[] fileBits = new byte[len];
```

Now I am searching for sulutions and can't find any. 
Maybe someone had solved it and could share some code, tips or idea.

```
if (file.length() > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("File is too large: " + file.length());
}

int len = (int) file.length();
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

try {
    byte[] fileBits = new byte[len];
    for (int pos = 0; pos < len;) {
        int n = inputStream.read(fileBits, pos, len - pos);
        if (n < 0) {
            throw new EOFException();
        }
        pos += n;
    }

inputStream.read(fileBits, 0, inputStream.available());
inputStream.close();
```

Comment: Do you really need the entire file at once? What prevents you from streaming it?

Comment: Did you try [searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=OutOfMemoryError) for `OutOfMemoryError`? See `java -mx`

Comment: Each index you create is 4 bytes.  500 million of them will try to allocate 2G of space.  You can't solve it this way without more memory or as josh.trow suggested buffer/streaming

Comment: The solution that worked for us was to use a machine with 96GB RAM (with appropriate -XMx option) instead of 24GB when our app ran out of memory.. :D.. seriously, though answer what Josh said..

Comment: @JohnVint how would creating a `byte` array use more than one byte per index?

Comment: The retained heap of an array of 1 element is 4 bytes (even if the index is not initialized).

Comment: Of course, there's a fixed overhead for each array, but that doesn't mean every `byte` in the array will actually use 4 bytes, right? If so, what's the point of all the different integer types? (byte, short, int, long)

Comment: @mgibsonbr  When I say it costs 4 bytes I only refer to the overhead incurred when creating an array, not its type.  If he is running on a 32 bit windows OS and he simply tries to create an array of 500 million elements, it will initially try to reserve 2G of heap and fail doing that.

Comment: Thank you guys it was quick for answers. Well i before tried to add more memory of VM in my netbeans VM Options typing -Xmx512m. But still this didn't helped. I think because i have just 1 GB of ram not 96 :D Just joke, I think i will try to use MappedByteBuffer to see what will be. Also as one answer was to use chunks of file reading. I thought it too but time how much it will take give me an idea to ask smarter people. I not just read these bits but convert them to chars and do some work with them :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you try memory mapping.

```
FileChannel fc = new FileInputStream(file).getChannel();
MappedByteBuffer mbb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, (int) fc.size());
```

This will make the whole file available almost immediately (about 10 ms) and uses next to no heap.  BTW The file has to be less than 2 GB.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to load the entire file to memory at once, I can only suggest increasing the memory available to Java. Try invoking your program using the `Xmx` (max heap size) or `Xms` (initial heap size) arguments (use the latter if you know beforehand how much memory you'll need, otherwise the former might be best).

```
java -Xms512m -Xmx1g BigApp
```

As an alternative, you can use NIO's [Memory-mapped files](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ314_029.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't open the whole file into memory. You need to create a byte array buffer with a fixed size, then you open your file from chunks of the size you defined.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a [`RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).